# TikZ keys: turn on a feature and set a parameter at the same time

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a custom shape defined using TikZ. This shape has an optional part; if this is to be drawn, the colour has to be specified.

So I'd like to be able to use the following syntax:

```
\node [MyShape] at (0,0) {}; % Draw the shape without the optional part
\node [MyShape, mycolour=blue] at (0,1) {}; % Draw the shape with the optional part in blue
```

I know how to use boolean keys to turn options on and off. I know how to use keys to pass colour parameters. But here I need to do both at once!

Comment: Try `\tikzset{/tikz/set and colour/.style={mycolour=#1,draw the optional part=true}}`

Comment: (Without a MWE it's hard to test to see if that's what you really want to do, hence posting as a comment rather than an answer.)

Comment: I want to be able to use exactly the example syntax provided in the question. The second example line should set a boolean variable to 'true', and store the colour that has been provided.

Comment: If you tell us exactly how the drawing and colouring are to be done, it'll be easier to give a precise answer.  As it is, the best we can do is give vague hints.

Comment: Jake's comment gives me exactly what I need.

Comment: @Jake That sounds like a cue for an answer to me ...

Comment: @Jake Done and dusted.

Answer (score 5):

Amalgamating the comments, it seems that you want to use `pgfkeys`' notion of *styles*.  These can take arguments, so:

```
\tikzset{
    /tikz/mycolour/.style={
         colour of optional part=#1,
         draw the optional part=true
    }
}
```

means that calling `mycolour=blue` sets both the colour of the optional part (assuming that is what `/tikz/colour of optional part=<colour>` does) and the flag to draw it (assuming that is what `/tikz/draw the optional part` controls).